# Dispatch MouseEvent

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, dispatchevent

Is there a way to dispatch `MouseEvent`, same as `dispatchKeyEvent` using the 
`KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(listener);`
that happens before the event transferred to the component ?

I know I have 2 options

1) add mouse event to all compoenents recursive

2) use a transparent glasspane

Does Java support this , or do I have to use the one of the options above?

thank you

Comment: Can the java.awt.Robot class help you ?

Comment: i didn't come to think of that ,
this is totally cool come to think about it :) 
let me check :)

Comment: java.awt.Robot will give me the ability to move mouse 
but i don't see any way to register MouseListener to it 
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i finally did was

```
long  eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
         + AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK;
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(
         new MouseListener(){....}, eventMask);
```

thank you alll

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried `java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)`?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

JButton jb = new JButton("Press!");
MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(jb, // which
    MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, // what
    System.currentTimeMillis(), // when
    0, // no modifiers
    10, 10, // where: at (10, 10}
    1, // only 1 click 
    false); // not a popup trigger

jb.dispatchEvent(me);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally used this:

```
        a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(a,
                               MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                               System.currentTimeMillis() + 10,
                               MouseEvent.NOBUTTON,
                              x,y,
                               0,
                               false));
```

Some explanation for params:
X Mouse X to move
Y Mouse Y to move
A is the component
I hope i have been helpfull for people with the same question.